# Using dplyr::lag to calculate days since first event

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I am trying to use dplyr::lag to determine the number of days that have passed for each event since the initial event but I am getting unexpected behavior.

Example, very simple data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2"),
                 date= c("4/1/2020", "4/2/2020", "4/3/2020", "4/4/2020", "4/17/2020", "4/18/2020"))

df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

id      date
1  1  4/1/2020
2  1  4/2/2020
3  1  4/3/2020
4  1  4/4/2020
5  2 4/17/2020
6  2 4/18/2020
```

What I was hoping to do was create a new column days_since_first_event that calculated the number of days between the initial event by id and each subsequent date with this expected output

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(days_since_first_event = as.numeric(date - lag(date)))

id      date days_since_first_event
1  1  4/1/2020                      0
2  1  4/2/2020                      1
3  1  4/3/2020                      2
4  1  4/4/2020                      3
5  2 4/17/2020                      0
6  2 4/18/2020                      1
```

But instead I get this output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
  id    date       days_since_first_event
  <chr> <date>                      <dbl>
1 1     2020-04-01                     NA
2 1     2020-04-02                      1
3 1     2020-04-03                      1
4 1     2020-04-04                      1
5 2     2020-04-17                     NA
6 2     2020-04-18                      1
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are probably looking for `df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(days_since_first_event = date - first(date))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first n values of `lag()` get a default value, because you don't have 'older' data. The default value is `NA`. Hence the `NA` in your results.

Furthermore, using lag will only yield the difference between consecutive events.

Comment: Just to be clear, for id 1, lag works for 2020-04-01 and 2020-04-02 but would not work for 2020-04-01 and 2020-04-03 because those dates are not consecutive? Thanks for that clarification and for explaining the behavior for initial values. Between your reply and the solution to use first() I have my answers.